# Build/Automated-deployment tool recommendations for node.js

Tags: node.js, deployment, build

I'm currently trying to set up automated deployment for our node.js based system.  I've been doing quite a bit of research, but nothing really has jumped out as the obvious choice of tool to automate what I'm trying to do, which can be summarised as:

- Pull code from central Mercurial repo into build-server build directory.
- Concat/Minify relevant client side JS
- For each server :

  - SSH into box
  - copy relevant files over SSH (SCP or whatever) (different code for different server roles)
  - restart relevant processes.

I'm probably going to use [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) for the high-level management of this, but am undecided on the tool to use to actually script the work.

It doesn't have to be a JS based build script, but that's an option (although I'm not entirely convinced that JS is the right language for this stuff anyway).  Would be ok with Python or Bash style solutions.

What's a sane/robust choice capable of the tasks listed above?

Thank you!

UPDATE: Sorry, I didn't mention before, but ideally I'd like to have the build tasks run on a central Build/Deployment server, and not locally on the development machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays I am using [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki) for all my deployment needs. Be it PHP, Ruby or Node.

There are recipes for almost all situations, but with experience, it is easy to build your own. You can hook your own commands to certain events in deployment process.

Capistrano uses SSH to access production or staging servers and issue commands remotely.

Here are some recipes for node.js (but I have not tried them):

https://github.com/loopj/capistrano-node-deploy

Comment: That's interesting, thanks.  I like the fact that it's SSH/Multi server focused.  My only concerns are 1: That it's ruby based - I know nothing about ruby (Gems etc mean nothing to me), although I understand most of the scripts are in a DSL. and 2: I was hoping for all the build/deploy mechanics to happen on a central build/deployment server - I wanted to avoid having intricate installation requirements on developer machines (as I understand it, capistrano is intended to be run from local dev machines - please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: 1: There is not much ruby in Capfiles, it's more "ruby like" than pure ruby. Might be confusing at start, but is worth the effort. As you will be able to use Capistrano in many of your future projects once you grasp it.
2: I usually use Jenkins as my continuous integration server, and after builds and tests are done, I invoke Capistrano commands, to deploy my application to the staging server. So it can be used by a central server. But I have not tried to deploy to the same server. I have separate CI and staging servers.

Comment: Re 2: Ah, that's great then.  We have separate CI and staging servers too.  I didn't realise it was geared towards running on a CI server.  Thanks.

Comment: In the end I went with Fabric, which seems pretty similar to Capistrano, but Python based (I'm more familiar with Python than Ruby).  I'm accepting this as the best answer though.

Answer (score 3):

In case it is of any value to users in the future, I ended up going with [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org).

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on using your own servers to host the app, you can always use [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/) for the automation. You can write custom tasks for it and do whatever you want, or find some for the mentioned cases in the community. I believe minification and such already exist.

As a personal recommendation, though, I can say I've been happy with hosting my node apps on [NodeJitsu](http://nodejitsu.com/) (paid service). They provide a command-line utility installed through npm, which can copy your code to their cloud, do a snapshot and start the app automatically. This is the easiest deployment scenario I've ever done.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah we wont be using something like nodejitsu. Besides the fact that I think it's surrendering a little too much to the service provider, Node is just one part of the system (albeit the main part) - we've got other server roles too.    I took a look at grunt.js - it seems quite popular, but I gave up on it in the end - a lot of the documentation linked to in the Github page is 404, and I couldn't figure out how to e.g. SSH with it.  Plus I'm not overly keen on the declarative stlye - would prefer something more procedural.

Comment: I see. I would advise that you rephrase your search as a general purpose command-line deploy tool then. It seems you're not searching for a node specific tool.

Comment: Well, I was hoping there was something with general-purpose capabilities, but which worked well with node (perhaps e.g. running on node utilising JS for scripting).  It would be good not to have to rely on too many technologies.  But yeah, I'll clarify this in the question/title later if it's misleading people.